# Yodlee stop refresh

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to stop the refresh via [stopRefresh](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/stopRefresh). For example if the user decide to not answer the MFA.

I tried to set the siteAccountId and itemAccountId for the parameter itemId but I always get this error.

```
{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.InvalidItemException","referenceCode":"_bc8515a0-ffad-49ae-935d-96971c833c09","message":"Argument value not found: XXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Where XXXXXXXXXX is the siteAccountId or itemAccountId.

Is this method supported by the API ? Why set siteAccountId or itemAccountId as the itemId parameter is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Container Based Approach then you have to use stopRefresh to stop an ongoing refresh, and as an input in that API you have to provide the itemId/memItemId which you would have received in the response of addItemForContentService1 API. Passing SiteAccountId or ItemAccountId won't work.

In case if you using Site Based approach then you have to use stopSiteRefresh, while passing memSiteAccId/SiteAccountId which you would have received in the response of addSiteAccount1.

The error you are getting comes when you pass an incorrect value(which doesn't exist for this user).